# How to debug aspx pages after ajax post back?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, postback

I'm working on a project that have a particular architecture.

On `page_load` event we have a `switch case`

```
    switch (command)
    {
          case "LOAD":
              load();
              break;
          case "UNLOAD":
              unload();
          case "SAVE":
              save();
              break;
    }
```

In aspx pages with a custom Ajax method we put something in *command variable* and in post back we make decision which methods should be called on `page_load` event.

```
    //this is a custom method which works fine
    var postData = "Command=LOAD";
    AjaxPost(postData, null, null, function (data) {
            if ($.trim(data) != "") {
              //something
            }
    });
```

My question is, how am I able to debug methods in my `switch case` statement? Response.Wirte(), and javascript alert dont work in here. I'm not sure if `Breakpoint` with this kind of post backs works or not, but because of our particular architecture we can not debug anythings with breakpoint and for this reason I don't reffer to breakspoints at all.

Note:We use Ajax and post back is not generated from submit, in other words, page shouldn't refresh.

Comment: Breakpoint should stop any server call, not just asp:button click.

Comment: @kobe Thanks, But because of our particular architecture we are not able to use breakpoint. Reason is we have several solutions and they only work after we publish them and put them together. Is there any alternative way than breakpoint?

Comment: If it's something specific you can write to a text file

Comment: Thanks, write to a text file works fine, now I can debug my code with this approach, but @Avner solution is much more easier if I can solve problems with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the pdb file for the assembly is deployed in the bin folder.

Then add this above the switch:

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()

Which will launch debugger when that section is hit  by your Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, I like your approach, now debugger is waiting in specified line. But it have two problems. 1) why I can not go to next line using step over or step into? 2) why I can not see values of variables?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have debug symbols deployed with your dll. Is there pdb file in your bin folder?

Comment: Yes I deployed pdb files in my bin folder. If I didn't do that debugger wouldn't wait on breakpoint. Now it wait but `step over` and `step into` options are disable. Also if I move mouse courser on a variable it don't show me its value, instead it show me what is variable type. I don't run my project with F5, instead I deploy it and run it with going to localhost. Should I run my project in other ways?

Comment: Are you doing a debug or release build? Make sure in your advanced build settings your Debug Info setting is "full". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4wcexbc.aspx